# SMS senderId 11 characters length

Tags: url, sms, sender

I am using SMS clients for sending notifications for users in my MVC App.

**PROBLEM:** I would like to use my company name in senderId, but it's longer than 11 characters.

I read a lot references telling that SernderId (sender name which is shown on phone) is limited for 11 AlphaNumeric characters.

My questions are:

- Why it is 11 characters length? Is it something in common with 160 characters 
  sms length that towers safely transfer or just another reason?
- Is there any way to extend it to be longer?

Also code for this looks the same for all programming languages I think, because you just create url and pass parameters, then call that url and get response, so passing longer value for parameter name "from" does not work.

```
...
params+= "&from=" + sender;   // here is SenderId which is limited
params+= "&message=" + msg;
params+= "&recipient=" + phoneNumber;
params += "&url=" + CallbackUrl + "?smsid=" + SmsID;
```

Any thoughts, informations, confirmation is appreaciated. If someone can confirm, that it is not possible, so I will stop believing and trying to do something about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SMS Sender id goes into Address field of low level SS7 map protocol, which has this limitation, so there is no way you can use more chars unfortunately.
It comes from old times when there was no SMS, only Pager service.

Comment: thanks you very much for clearing this out for me  ;)

Comment: Also notice, you may encounter some problems on some phones due to SW bugs :) Posted Apple bug 1yr ago, still not solved, also on some Android phones, if concatenated SMS is used together with Alphanumeric sender id